# Intel XDK code works on emulator but not on real device

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I am doing simple accelerometer test on my device GT-N7100 , the code simply is like following:

```
function getSingleAcceleration() {
intel.xdk.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(
       function(evt){
       document.getElementById("accelerometerReadings").innerHTML=
       'Acceleration X: ' + evt.x + '<br/>' +
       'Acceleration Y: ' + evt.y + '<br/>' +
       'Acceleration Z: ' + evt.z + '<br/>' +
       'Timestamp: '      + evt.timestamp;
       }, {adjustForRotation:false});
}
        setInterval(getSingleAcceleration,1000)
```

which works well on intel XDK emulator , but when i test it on my device , all the readings are 0 , the time stamp is being updated though.

any idea why would this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this demo app (https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova) that I've put together just for this purpose. It is filled with comments and console.log messages so you can better see how some of these APIs work. Currently it only uses the Cordova accelerometer APIs, I hope to update it to also use the devicemotion apis and the intel xdk apis.

If this demo app is not providing any numbers then I would say there is some other issue in the way, I've tested it on a wide variety of devices and the accelerometer part always works (can't say that about other aspects, though :).

One thing you may have forgotten is waiting for the device ready event, nothing can happen until the underlying native code has been initialized, which is what the device ready event signals.

Comment: thanks for the answer , actually corodova works for me , but what im asking about is intel api , is there a problem with intel api ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, if you can provide a simple example app that reproduces the issue on the forum we can take a look and see what's going on.